# Why aren't my Joomla 3 articles translating to my new language?

Tags: joomla, multilingual, joomla-extensions, joomla-article

On the last version of Joomla 3, each link, module, and article could be associated with a language.

I installed a new language from AdminCP (Joomla 3 has an integrated install language on administrator). Now when I create an article, I continue to see only English options for language, and not the new language I just installed

What is missing? Is it necessary to install a component?

I think Joomla 3 don't need a component like joomfish, because the content can be multi-language as a native feature.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the language you installed as a content language in the language manager.

Comment: Thanks. So it's not require install some component? How to add change language on frontend?

Comment: You need to create your list of content languages in the language manager. Then you can select languages for your content (the language packs just handle the terms coming from the core components like "search" "Password" and so on).  If you want to implement a multilingual site you need to read this document:
http://multilingual-joomla-demo.cloudaccess.net/multi-lingual-steps-by-steps.html